# Are $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$ axioms?

Tags: axioms, quaternions

Regarding the quaternions definition:

$$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$$

I wounder if these are *axioms*, i.e. a *self-evident truth that requires no proof*? If not, how $ijk = -1$ is derived?

Comment: It is a definition of the multiplication rules for the quaternions.

Comment: those are the generators of a $\mathbb{R}$ algebra called the quaternions

Comment: The phrase "self-evident truth that requires no proof" is a long out-dated definition of the word axiom. Axioms are just the premises of a theory, and you can make them be whatever you want - of course, if the axioms are nonsense, then the resulting theory will be nonsense. There are many examples of axioms which are not "self-evident truths" - take, for example, the generally accepted axioms of set theory, ZFC. I don't know when the transition in attitude toward axioms occurred, but at a guess, I would imagine probably around the 19th century when non-Euclidean geometry was being discovered.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I agree with what you say, but doesnt axiomatisation go back to Euclid ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus "transition in attitude" meaning transition from self-evident truths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are definitions.

$$i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$$

Also, from definition, we have $ij=k$, hence

$$ijk=k^2=-1.$$